# Many emoji characters are not read by python file read

Tags: python, unicode, emoji, python-unicode

I have a list of 1500 emoji character dictionary in a json file, and I wanted to import those to my python code, I did a file read and convert it to a python dictionary but now I have only 143 records. How can I import all the emoji to my code, this is my code.

```
import sys
import ast

file = open('emojidescription.json','r').read()
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
emoji_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(file.translate(non_bmp_map))

#word = word.replaceAll(",", " ");

keys = list(emoji_dictionary["emojis"][0].keys())
values = list(emoji_dictionary["emojis"][0].values())

file_write = open('output.txt','a')

print(len(keys))
for i in range(len(keys)):
    try:
        content = 'word = word.replace("{0}", "{1}")'.format(keys[i],values[i][0])
    except Exception as e:
        content = 'word = word.replace("{0}", "{1}")'.format(keys[i],'')
    #file.write()
    #print(keys[i],values[i])
    print(content)


file_write.close()
```

This is my input sample

```
{

    "emojis": [
        {

            "‍": ["Graduate"],
            "©": ["Copy right"],
            "®": ["Registered"],
            "‍‍": ["family"],
            "‍❤️‍‍": ["love"],
            "™": ["trademark"],
            "‍❤‍": ["love"], 
            "⌚": ["time"],
            "⌛": ["wait"], 
            "⭐": ["star"],
            "": ["Elephant"],
            "": ["Cat"],
            "": ["ant"],
            "": ["cock"],
            "": ["cock"],
```

This is my result, and the 143 denotes number of emoji.

> 143
>
> word = word.replace("�‍�‍�‍�", "family")
>
> word = word.replace("Ⓜ", "")
>
> word = word.replace("♥", "")
>
> word = word.replace("♠", "")
>
> word = word.replace("⌛", "wait")

Comment: Can you give us an input sample?

Comment: Thanks. Any particular reason that you're not using the `json` module?

Comment: Not really, I am a newbie to python, and I don't have much experience with the json module.

Comment: Your inout example is not really helpful with the inages inside. But I guess touvdid not encode / escape the unicode characters properly as required in JSON.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the input sample (SO is just interpreting the utf-8 into unicode for display -- as it should)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're seeing only 143 records from an input of 1500 (your sample doesn't seem to display this behavior).

The setup doesn't seem to do anything useful, but what you're doing boils down to (simplified and skipping lots of details):

```
d = ..read json as python dict.
keys = d.keys()
values = d.values()
for i in range(len(keys)):
    key = keys[i]
    value = values[i]
```

and that should be completely correct. There are better ways to do this in Python, however, like using the `zip` function:

```
d = ..read json as python dict.
keys = d.keys()
values = d.values()
for key, value in zip(keys, values):  # zip picks pair-wise elements
    ...
```

or simply asking the dict for its items:

```
for key, value in d.items():
    ...
```

The `json` module makes reading and writing json much simpler (and safer), and using the idiom from above the problem reduces to this:

```
import json

emojis = json.load(open('emoji.json', 'rb'))

with open('output.py', 'wb') as fp:
    for k,v in emojis['emojis'][0].items():
        val = u'word = word.replace("{0}", "{1}")\n'.format(k, v[0] if v else "")
        fp.write(val.encode('u8'))
```

Comment: You're welcome. The reason MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and sample input are so important is that most of us try out code samples locally before posting them, having code + data makes it much more likely that the answer is correct and useful...

Comment: You are using a python version with 16bit-Unicode. So you cannot handle emojis, which are at code points > 0xFFFF.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you replace all emojis with `0xfffd` in the lines:

```
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
emoji_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(file.translate(non_bmp_map))
```

Just don't to this!

Using json:

```
import json

with open('emojidescription.json', encoding="utf8") as emojis:
    emojis = json.load(emojis)

with open('output.txt','a', encoding="utf8") as output:
    for emoji, text in emojis["emojis"][0].items():
        text = "" if not text else text[0]
        output.write('word = word.replace("{0}", "{1}")\n'.format(emoji, text))
```